# How to merge .pdf and .jpg file in one pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

There are two files on disk .jpg and .pdf, i need to read both files and add them to new pdf and send to browser so that it can be downloaded.

New pdf file only contains pdf contents not jpeg file image.

```
          memoryStream myMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        //----pdf file--------------

        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy writer2 = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy(doc, myMemoryStream);

        doc.Open();

        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(imagepath + "/30244.pdf");
        reader.ConsolidateNamedDestinations();

        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++) {
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage page = writer2.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
            writer2.AddPage(page);
        }

        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRAcroForm form = reader.AcroForm;
        if (form != null) {
            writer2.CopyAcroForm(reader);
        }

        //-----------------jpeg file-------------------------------------
        MemoryStream myMemoryStream2 = new MemoryStream();
        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imagepath + "/Vouchers.jpg");
        iTextSharp.text.Document doc2 = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc2, myMemoryStream2);
        doc2.Open();
        iTextSharp.text.Image pdfImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

       doc2.Add(pdfImage);

       doc2.close();
       doc.close();

        byte[] content = myMemoryStream.ToArray;

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=LeftCorner568.pdf");
        Response.BinaryWrite(content);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've been having trouble with this for a while now I'm going to give you a long-ish answer that will hopefully help you.

First, I don't have access to an ASP.Net server so I'm running everything from a folder on the desktop. So instead of reading and writing from and to relative paths you'll see me working from `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)`. I'm assuming that you'll be able to swap your paths in later.

Second, (and not that it really matter) I don't have SSRS so instead I created a helper method that makes a fake PDF for me to work from that returns a PDF as a byte array:

```
/// <summary>
/// Create a fake SSRS report
/// </summary>
/// <returns>A valid PDF stored as a byte array</returns>
private Byte[] getSSRSPdfAsByteArray() {
    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream()) {
        using (var doc = new Document()) {
            using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms)) {
                doc.Open();
                doc.Add(new Paragraph("This is my SSRS report"));
                doc.Close();
            }
        }

        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Third, just so that we're on the same page and to have something to work with I created two additional helper methods that generate some sample images and PDFs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Create sample images in the folder provided
/// </summary>
/// <param name="count">The number of images to create</param>
/// <param name="workingFolder">The folder to create images in</param>
private void createSampleImages(int count, string workingFolder) {
    var random = new Random();
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        using (var bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(200, 200)) {
            using (var g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
                g.Clear(Color.FromArgb(random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255)));
            }
            bmp.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(workingFolder, string.Format("Image_{0}.jpg", i)));
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Create sample PDFs in the folder provided
/// </summary>
/// <param name="count">The number of PDFs to create</param>
/// <param name="workingFolder">The folder to create PDFs in</param>
private void createSamplePDFs(int count, string workingFolder) {
    var random = new Random();
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream()) {
            using (var doc = new Document()) {
                using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms)) {
                    doc.Open();
                    var pageCount = random.Next(1, 10);
                    for (var j = 0; j < pageCount; j++) {
                        doc.NewPage();
                        doc.Add(new Paragraph(String.Format("This is page {0} of document {1}", j, i)));
                    }
                    doc.Close();
                }
            }

            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(System.IO.Path.Combine(workingFolder, string.Format("File_{0}.pdf", i)), ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Just to reiterate, you obviously wouldn't have a need for these three helper methods, they're just so that you and I have a common set of files to work from. These helper methods are also intentionally not commented.

Fourth, at the end of the code below I'm storing the final PDF into a byte array called `finalFileBytes` and I'm then writing that to disk. Once again, I'm working on the desktop so this is where you'd do `Response.BinaryWrite(finalFileBytes)` instead.

Fifth, there's different ways to merge and combine files. `PdfCopy`, `PdfSmartCopy` and `PdfStamper` are all commonly used. I encourage you to read the [official iText/iTextSharp book](https://www.manning.com/books/itext-in-action-second-edition) or at least the free Chapter 6, *Working with existing PDFs* that goes into great detail about this. In the code below I'm using `PdfSmartCopy` and I'm converting each image to a PDF before importing them. There might be a better way but I'm not sure if you can do it all in one pass or not. Bruno would know better than me. But the below works.

See the individual code comments for more details on what's going on.

```
//The folder that all of our work will be done in
var workingFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Pdf Test");

//This is the final PDF that we'll create for testing purposes
var finalPDF = System.IO.Path.Combine(workingFolder, "test.pdf");

//Create our working directory if it doesn't exist already
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(workingFolder);

//Create sample PDFs and images
createSampleImages(10, workingFolder);
createSamplePDFs(10, workingFolder);

//Create our sample SSRS PDF byte array
var SSRS_Bytes = getSSRSPdfAsByteArray();

//This variable will eventually hold our combined PDF as a byte array
Byte[] finalFileBytes;

//Write everything to a MemoryStream
using (var finalFile = new System.IO.MemoryStream()) {

    //Create a generic Document
    using (var doc = new Document()) {

        //Use PdfSmartCopy to intelligently merge files
        using (var copy = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, finalFile)) {

            //Open our document for writing
            doc.Open();

            //#1 - Import the SSRS report

            //Bind a reader to our SSRS report
            using (var reader = new PdfReader(SSRS_Bytes)) {

                //Loop through each page
                for (var i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++) {

                    //Add the imported page to our final document
                    copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, i));
                }
            }

            //#2 - Image the images

            //Loop through each image in our working directory
            foreach (var f in System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(workingFolder, "*.jpg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)) {

                //There's different ways to do this and it depends on what exactly "add an image to a PDF" really means
                //Below we add each individual image to a PDF and then merge that PDF into the main PDF
                //This could be optimized greatly

                //From https://alandjackson.wordpress.com/2013/09/27/convert-an-image-to-a-pdf-in-c-using-itextsharp/

                //Get the size of the current image
                iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageSize = null;
                using (var srcImage = new Bitmap(f)) {
                    pageSize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0, 0, srcImage.Width, srcImage.Height);
                }

                //Will eventually hold the PDF with the image as a byte array
                Byte[] imageBytes;

                //Simple image to PDF
                using (var m = new MemoryStream()) {
                    using (var d = new Document(pageSize, 0, 0, 0, 0)) {
                        using (var w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(d, m)) {
                            d.Open();
                            d.Add(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(f));
                            d.Close();
                        }
                    }

                    //Grab the bytes before closing out the stream
                    imageBytes = m.ToArray();
                }

                //Now merge using the same merge code as #1
                using (var reader = new PdfReader(imageBytes)) {
                    for (var i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++) {
                        copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, i));
                    }
                }
            }

            //#3 - Merge additional PDF

            //Look for each PDF in our working directory
            foreach (var f in System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(workingFolder, "*.pdf", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)) {

                //Because I'm writing samples files to disk but not cleaning up afterwards
                //I want to avoid adding my output file as an input file
                if (f == finalPDF) {
                    continue;
                }

                //Now merge using the same merge code as #1
                using (var reader = new PdfReader(f)) {
                    for (var i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++) {
                        copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, i));
                    }
                }
            }

            doc.Close();
        }
    }

    //Grab the bytes before closing the stream
    finalFileBytes = finalFile.ToArray();
}

//At this point finalFileBytes holds a byte array of a PDF
//that contains the SSRS PDF, the sample images and the
//sample PDFs. For demonstration purposes I'm just writing to
//disk but this could be written to the HTTP stream
//using Response.BinaryWrite()

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(finalPDF, finalFileBytes);
```