# Problems loading iTextSharp in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, itext

I am having problem loading the iTextSharp.dll in PowerShell.  Sometimes it works fine using either:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\dll\itextsharp.dll")

Add-Type -Path C:\dll\itextsharp.dll'
```

However, most times I get the following error:

```
Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s):
    "Could not load file or assembly 'file:/// C:\dll\itextsharp.dll'
    or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported.
    (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)"
At line:1 char:1
+ [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("itextsharp.dll")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileLoadException
```

I have tried unblocking the file but I still get the error above.

Comment: I wonder if that is a 32-bit assembly and you are in x64 PowerShell? Also does it make a difference if you are running as admin.

Comment: Looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524423/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-hresult-0x80131515-when-adding-controller-to-m) on StackOverflow will probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524423/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-hresult-0x80131515-when-adding-controller-to-m) on StackOverflow will probably solve your problem. Apparently you need to add the option `<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />` to the .EXEs config file to load an assembly from a network share.

I found this by searching for the HRESULT 0x80131515

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the DLL works with PowerShell ISE (x86), but not the 64-bit version of PowerShell ISE.